# Why is Gaia so much dimmer than we thought?

Tags: spacecraft, observation, gaia

The ESA is using ground-based telescopes to precisely gauge the position of the Gaia satellite. But the satellite appears at about the 21st magnitude, three magnitudes dimmer (~16 times) than expected!

Why is this? If we can accurately measure the reflectance of the sunshield (as I assume has been done!), wouldn't it be a reasonably simple matter to calculate its apparent magnitude?

Comment: Actually, [according to ESA](http://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/news_20140729): _"...the spacecraft turned out to be at the faintest end of its estimated brightness range."_ Why is another matter though, likely pretty complex and I'm not sure there's any consensus even among its operators for the exact cause. I suspect it's a set of circumstances, from the Gaia's outgassing of trapped ice that also likely caused its "stray light" problems and it might have damaged its thermal tent in the process, to repositioning the craft's angle to the Sun to help alleviate that problem.

Comment: @TildalWave That press release is later, but it doesn't correlate with this [pre-launch paper](http://issfd.org/ISSFD_2012/ISSFD23_OD2_5.pdf). It's the best I could dig up (technical data on spacecraft can be frustratingly hard to find), but the authors say Gaia was expected to have a visible magnitude between 17 and 19 -  *"mainly because of its larger size and despite its unfavourably large Sun aspect angle the brightness of Gaia is expected to be similar to that of Planck"*. The mystery as to why still remains, and you're probably correct in that no one can account for all of the difference

Comment: Yes, sadly, ESA oftentimes, organizationally speaking, comes out as a confused hydra.

Comment: @TildalWave True, but in fairness some information is published [in the literature](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012Ap%26SS.341...31D), and it's simply not feasible to divulge every internal document. But the few papers I scanned through don't have what I need! Also, paywalls are a huge turn-off for amateurs who just want to read about it for fun (why not publish as open access?), and the ESA's outreach site on the telescope has a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: The conductive glass over the solar panels is known to blacken over time from radiation damage.  For how long had Gaia been in space before they tried to observe it with a ground-based telescope?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I've been able to find, the cause is not known yet.

They didn't do brightness measurements before launch, and brightness can vary dramatically depending on e.g. the viewing angle. So the expectation was never more than a rough estimate.

From a paper published in Q1 2014 (a few months after launch), "[GBOT - Ground Based Optical Tracking of the Gaia satellite](http://gbot.obspm.fr/gbotpipeline/spie9149-25.pdf)":

> The brightness of the main target of a campaign such as Gaia is probably the single most important piece of information. Unfortunately it is also one of the hardest to obtain, since in most cases the satellite is being assembled on the ground while the campaign is set up.
>
> While it looks rather straightforward at first to draw some conclusion based on basic principles, such as area, reflectivity, etc. in practice this is a very complicated process, since it depends on the reflective quantities of the material, which are not always available because of industrial secrets, and may furthermore change over time, due to effects like radiation damage - the L2 is a high radiation environment.
>
> Other factors are the aspect angle, the azimuth angle (which is constantly changing for a spinning object like Gaia), and many other issues. In order to get a strong estimate for the predicted brightness of Gaia, the GBOT group did apply to perform measurements, however this proposal was retracted after it was found to be too costly to perform.
>
> Therefore we had to rely on our experience with other space craft, namely those we were observing during our tests, i.e. mainly WMAP and Planck; While Planck has a widely different shape and probably also reflective characteristics, see Fig. 5, WMAP was essentially a smaller version of Gaia inclined by half the angle of Gaia, i.e. 22.5◦ instead of 45◦.
>
> WMAP in general had a magnitude in R of 18-18.5, Planck about 18 mag. Therefore it seemed safe to assume that conservatively speaking, Gaia has roughly the same magnitude. This turned out to be not the case. For reasons not yet entirely understood (exposed structures, etc.?) Gaia turned out to be more than 2 mags fainter than Planck, leading to the need to reevaluate the whole GBOT program, as described in Sect. 6.
>
> This still ongoing process formed the main activities of the GBOT
> team during the opening months of 2014. Now, with several months having elapsed since the launch, we have a somewhat better grasp of the magnitude range of Gaia; it was found to be between 20 and 21.2, depending on the distance, the Earth aspect angle k , and other factors. It was known before that spacecraft can show rapid and long term variability of unknown origin, e.g. the unusual faintness followed by unusual brightness of Planck during the OR3 (see Sect. 4.)

Gaia was launched on 2013-12-19, observations listed in the paper were 2014-01-07 to 2014-02-26, i.e. from 19 days after launch. That makes radiation blackening unlikely as a cause for the less-than-expected brightness.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why it might be especially hard to detect. Let me give a few of the most common ones.

First of all, materials change with respect to time in space. The first, and usually largest, process happens during the out-gassing phase, which essentially happens in the first few days of a spacecraft, where any gasses trapped in materials escapes. There are rumors in the space industry of companies using non space approved materials to clean optical surfaces, and those optical surfaces (Or solar panels) ended up darkening over the course of several months to a year later, ending in a loss of the satellite. Outgassing is a serious issue!

Another possibility is that radiation, solar wind, etc could have damaged some of the visible components, perhaps leading to a lower visibility. For instance, I understand small plastic components, which often hold antennas in place for launch, are degraded with time in space.

Lastly is the orientation of the spacecraft. If the spacecraft was pointed differently than expected, it would appear to be dimmer than expected. Some spacecraft have a huge profile of how they are seen, depending on their orientation! If something is reflected in a specular manner, there can be a huge glint if it reflects light directly from the Sun, or even the Earth. This could even be the result from a fairly small component. These things are quite difficult to predict, leading to a fair amount of uncertainty.